# Failed to resolve Xamarin.Forms.INavigation Xamarin.Forms.NavigableElement::get_Navigation()

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have upgraded to latest Xamarin.Froms on Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition and Target Device and API to Android Q (Level 29)
While Building solution in Debug Mode, it builds successfully but when I am trying to run in Debug or release mode on device then it is giving error.

As per the error issue is in

```
System.Void TestAppAndroid.Views.BarCodes`1/b__1_2>d::MoveNext()
```

But I dont see any Navigation code in this view. It is only have ListView element which Binds to a static data source.

```
Error       MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void TestAppAndroid.Views.BarCodes`1/b__1_2>d::MoveNext()' in assembly: 'TestAppAndroid.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Xamarin.Forms.INavigation Xamarin.Forms.NavigableElement::get_Navigation()
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
    at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
    at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()            0
```

Comment: If it worked fine before you update it . You can clean the crash:delete the folder `bin` and `obj` in Android and Share Project .Then clean and rebuild it. In addition ,make sure that the version of xamarin.forms in your solution has been updated to newest version .

Comment: I tried. Removed both obj and Bin from Android and Shared project, Cleaned project and rebuild. rebuild successful but when tried to run on device, same error occurred

Comment: Try to create a new blank project and check if has the same issue.